# Adding custom mime-type using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, mime-types

I have a question about mime-types. I found found information how to add custom tags to html document using document.registerElement function. Is there a similar way to register own mime-types? I know how to do it using native language plugins for web browser but I'm interested only in potential JavaScript solution.

For example I would like to DOM element

```
<object type="my_own_mime_type"/>
```

Comment: What for? What would registering your mime type let you do?

Comment: Usually, you do it with the type attribute when required, for example `<script type='text/javascript'>` - what are you actually trying to do?